# how to serve dynamic content in playframework 2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have an application where some images will be dynamically created based on user input and I need to send those images back to the user's browser. Once the user leaves the page the images are on, the images won't be needed anymore, so I just need them around long enough to serve them.

I understand how to use `Ok(sendFile(...))` or `Ok(stream(...))` within a controller to send the image data, but what I can't wrap my head around is how I'd specify the path for the `src` in the `img` tag. More explicitly, I presume I will have something like

```
<img src=@routes.Controllers.serveImage(...) />
```

somewhere in my template.

Ideally, I wouldn't have to create temp files to hold the images since that's an awful lot of input/output that might not need to happen, although it does seem to be the easiest way to get a unique identifier that I could pass to the `serveImage` controller.

If I try to serve the images from memory, how would I provide a unique id for the image, make sure that it's available in memory when the web browser asks for it, and get rid of it when it's no longer needed?

Thanks!
Todd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating [unique ids is quite simple](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html).

The "serve the images from memory, [...] get rid of it when it's no longer needed" part sounds a lot like caching to me. Play provides a [Caching API](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaCache) for that.

Comment: Thanks for not being too condescending when you answered that. As soon as I went to bed, the phrase "use the Cache" came to me.

Comment: Would this also be a good approach for dynamically generated images that may want to live on my server for a while? Or if this confuses the original question, I can just post a new one...Still, the question title refers to serving dynamic content so others looking for what I'm asking about may end up here anyway?

Comment: @JDischler I don't know your exact use case (might be worth a question, the comment fields are so small ;-) ), but off the top of my head, I'd go with a solution where I don't cache the images with Play in any way, but rather on my frontend HTTP server (I'm using nginx). Of course, this can only work if your images are publicly accessible, you don't need to invoke logic in Play for each request and there is a unique mapping between image and URI.

Comment: We haven't identified a solid need for a frontend HTTP server at this point since Play! is serving up all of our forms/assets. From that angle, if the Play! server can generate dynamic images based on user entered criteria (or initiate a process to do it)...and then serve that image back to that user, this would keep our architecture a bit simpler. One small point - the image would likely need to persist for at least a while (on the order of minutes or hours) so we are wanting to send back a url to the image vs. the image data itself.

Comment: So...I decided to post my variant on this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547698/serving-dynamic-content-in-play-2-x  Hopefully it will not be considered a duplicate.